# How to make it so that every alternate character in a string appears as a hyphen

Tags: python

I have been asked to create a simple word guessing game that will select a random word from a list, but then displays that word with **every alternate letter replaced with a hyphen.**
I have figured out the selection of the random word, but after that I don't have any idea.
The prompt does mention using the modulus operator (`%`) within a for-loop to detect if a letter's position is odd or even, which I understand to an extent, but I cant figure out how to make it work in this case.

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Did you do some research?

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) is also worth a read.

Comment: Do you know how to loop over a string, and more specifically, do you know how to loop over a string with `enumerate`?

Answer (score 1):

Code using a for loop in Python:

```
word = "Python"  #Add your code for random words instead
ans = ""
for i in range(len(word)):
    if i%2 != 0:
        ans += "-"
    else:
        ans += word[i]
print(ans)
```

Output:

```
P-t-o-
```

Comment: This is greatly improved using `enumerate`. `for i, ch in enumerate(word): ...`

Answer (score 1):

You could get letters at even positions using a striding subscript (word[::2]) and join them with an hyphen. Make sure to have an extra space for the last letter in case the word has an even number of letters.

```
word = "Elephant"

hyphened = "-".join((word+' ')[::2])

print(hyphened)
E-e-h-n-
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is even simpler than a for loop:

```
original_word = "alternate"  #generate a word
word = list(original_word)   #split the string in chars
word[1::2]=["-"]*len(word[1::2])    #replace chars in odd positions with '-'
print(original_word)
print("".join(word))
```

Hope this is useful.